# WordPress - Create posts out of Media Library images

Tags: php, wordpress, image

My client has provided me with hundreds of images that have to be set as featured images for posts named after a part of the image's title. Those images were uploaded to the Media Library already.

**Is there a way to iterate through all of those files and process them with a function of my own?** I need to extract the title of each image, create a post based on that image's title and add two additional images to each post. I don't want to do it manualy because it would take me ages to get it done.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good start:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/

Use get_posts to get all the attachments (post_type => 'attachment'), then loop through the attachments and programmatically create your posts.  Add in a separate function to upload two additional photos while you are creating the post.

Comment: But will "get_posts" get all media files which are not assigned to any post as an attachment? Those media files are just uploaded, not assigned to anything.

Comment: Links to files in media libraries are stored in wp_posts, post_type -> "attachment".
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description
If it's uploaded via WP admin and you can see it in media library section, it's there.

Comment: Remember that everything in WordPress is a "post".  When you upload an image, a "post" is created with information about that image.  Using get_posts will return anything you want, so long as you specify the correct post_type.  In this case, 'attachment'.  Doesn't matter if that image is assigned to anything.